How to Separate Layouts For Different Role in Ant Design Umi React framework
I want to separate layouts for different roles. i have already
developed admin layout. Now, i need a student role.
I want to redirect student routes and layout after a student login and redirect admin layouts after a admin login.
config/config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'umi';
import { join } from 'path';

import defaultSettings from './defaultSettings';
import proxy from './proxy';
import routes from './routes';

const { REACT_APP_ENV } = process.env;

export default defineConfig({
  hash: true,
  // base: '/deena/',
  // publicPath: '/deena/',
  antd: {},
  dva: {
    hmr: true,
  },
  layout: {
    // https://umijs.org/zh-CN/plugins/plugin-layout
    locale: true,
    sliderWidth: 208,
    ...defaultSettings,
  },
  // https://umijs.org/zh-CN/plugins/plugin-locale
  locale: {
    default: 'en-US',
    antd: true,
    // default true, when it is true, will use `navigator.language` overwrite default
    baseNavigator: true,
  },
  dynamicImport: {
    loading: '@ant-design/pro-layout/es/PageLoading',
  },
  targets: {
    ie: 11,
  },
  // umi routes: https://umijs.org/docs/routing
  routes,

  // Theme for antd: https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme-cn
  theme: {
    'root-entry-name': 'variable',
  },
  // esbuild is father build tools
  // https://umijs.org/plugins/plugin-esbuild
  esbuild: {},
  title: false,
  ignoreMomentLocale: false,
  proxy: proxy[REACT_APP_ENV || 'dev'],
  // Fast refresh hot update
  fastRefresh: {},
  openAPI: [
    {
      requestLibPath: "import { request } from 'umi'",
      // or use the online version
      // schemaPath: "https://gw.alipayobjects.com/os/antfincdn/M%24jrzTTYJN/oneapi.json"
      schemaPath: join(__dirname, 'oneapi.json'),
      mock: false,
    },
    {
      requestLibPath: "import { request } from 'umi'",
      schemaPath: 'https://gw.alipayobjects.com/os/antfincdn/CA1dOm%2631B/openapi.json',
      projectName: 'swagger',
    },
  ],
  nodeModulesTransform: { type: 'none' },
  mfsu: {},
  webpack5: {},
  exportStatic: {},
});


config/routes.ts
export default [
  {
    path: '/user',
    layout: false,
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/user',
        routes: [
          {
            path: '/user/login',
            name: 'login',
            component: './user/Login',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        component: './404',
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    path: '/',
    routes: [
      { path: '/student', redirect: '/student/dashboard' },
      {
        path: '/student/dashboard',
        name: 'Dashboard',
        icon: 'smile',
        component: './Student/Dashboard',
      },
      {
        path: '/student/profile',
        name: 'Profile',
        icon: 'smile',
        component: './Student/Profile',
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    path: '/',
    routes: [
      { path: '/', redirect: '/dashboard' },
      {
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'dashboard',
        icon: 'appstore',
        routes: [
          {
            path: '/dashboard/analysis',
            name: 'analysis',
            component: './Dashboard/Analysis',
          },
          {
            path: '/dashboard/monitor',
            name: 'monitor',
            component: './Dashboard/Monitor',
          },
          {
            path: '/dashboard/workplace',
            name: 'workplace',
            component: './Dashboard/Workplace',
          },
        ],
      },
      // forms
      {
        path: '/form',
        icon: 'form',
        name: 'form',
        routes: [
          {
            path: '/form/basic-form',
            name: 'basicform',
            component: './Forms/BasicForm',
          },
          {
            path: '/form/step-form',
            name: 'stepform',
            component: './Forms/StepForm',
            hideChildrenInMenu: true,
            routes: [
              {
                path: '/form/step-form',
                redirect: '/form/step-form/info',
              }
            ],
          },
          {
            path: '/form/advanced-form',
            name: 'advancedform',
            authority: ['admin'],
            component: './Forms/AdvancedForm',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]

src/app.tsx
import type {Settings as LayoutSettings} from '@ant-design/pro-layout';
import {PageLoading, SettingDrawer} from '@ant-design/pro-layout';
import type {RunTimeLayoutConfig} from 'umi';
import {history, Link} from 'umi';
import RightContent from '@/components/RightContent';
import Footer from '@/components/Footer';
import {LinkOutlined} from '@ant-design/icons';
import defaultSettings from '../config/defaultSettings';
import type {RequestConfig} from "@@/plugin-request/request";
import type {RequestOptionsInit, ResponseError} from 'umi-request';
import {parseJwt} from "@/services/util/util";
import adminRoutes from './routes/adminRoutes';
import studentRoutes from './routes/studentRoutes';

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
const loginPath = '/user/login';

export const initialStateConfig = {
  loading: <PageLoading/>,
};

export async function getInitialState(): Promise<{
  settings?: Partial<LayoutSettings>;
  currentUser?: API.CurrentUser;
  loading?: boolean;
  token?: string;
}> {
  const fetchUserInfo = async () => {
    try {
      const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token') || '';
      const payload = parseJwt(token);
      const currentUser = JSON.parse(payload?.sub);
      const scope = payload?.scope;
      if (currentUser) {
        currentUser.scope = scope;
        return currentUser;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      history.push(loginPath);
    }
    return undefined;
  };

  if (history.location.pathname !== loginPath) {
    const currentUser = await fetchUserInfo();
    return {
      currentUser,
      settings: defaultSettings,
    };
  }
  return {
    settings: defaultSettings,
  };
}

const errorHandler = (error: ResponseError) => {
  if (error?.response?.status == 403) {
    history.push(loginPath);
  }
  throw error;
};

const authHeaderInterceptor = (url: string, options: RequestOptionsInit) => {
  const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
  const authHeader = {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`};
  return {
    url: `${url}`,
    options: {...options, interceptors: true, headers: authHeader}
  };
};

export const request: RequestConfig = {
  errorHandler,
  requestInterceptors: [authHeaderInterceptor],
};

function isExpiredToken() {
  const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
  if (token) {
    const base64Url = token.split(".")[1];
    const base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/");
    const jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(
      atob(base64)
        .split("")
        .map(function (c) {
          return "%" + ("00" + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        })
        .join("")
    );
    const {exp} = JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
    return Date.now() >= exp * 1000;
  }
  return true;
}

export const layout: RunTimeLayoutConfig = ({initialState, setInitialState}) => {
  // const userRole = initialState?.currentUser?.scope;
  const userRole: string = "student";

  // Determine routes based on user role
  const routes = userRole === 'admin' ? adminRoutes : studentRoutes;
  // console.log({routes});
  
  return {
    rightContentRender: () => <RightContent/>,
    disableContentMargin: false,
    footerRender: () => <Footer/>,
    onPageChange: () => {
      const {location} = history;
      if (isExpiredToken() && location.pathname !== loginPath) {
        history.push(loginPath);
      }
    },
    links: isDev
      ? [
        <Link key="openapi" to="/umi/plugin/openapi" target="_blank">
          <LinkOutlined/>
          <span>OpenAPI</span>
        </Link>,
      ]
      : [],
    menuHeaderRender: undefined,
    childrenRender: (children, props) => {
      return (
        <>
          {children}
          {!props.location?.pathname?.includes('/login') && (
            <SettingDrawer
              disableUrlParams
              enableDarkTheme
              settings={initialState?.settings}
              onSettingChange={(settings) => {
                setInitialState((preInitialState) => ({
                  ...preInitialState,
                  settings,
                }));
              }}
            />
          )}
        </>
      );
    },
    ...initialState?.settings,
    routes,
  };
};

